# HTTP - can i use POST as updating like PUT or it's only for creating?

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, rest, asp.net-web-api

I have tried to do something like that:

client:

```
 $scope.addItem = function (productId, quantity) {
            $http.post(API_BASE_URL + '/Card/AddItem?guid=' + cartGuid, { productId: productId, quantity: quantity }).success(function (data) {
                alert('added succesfully');
            });
```

server :

```
     [HttpPost]
            [Route("AddItem")]
            public IHttpActionResult AddItem(Guid guid, int productId, int quantity = 1)
            {
                var cart = this._rep.Get<Cart>().SingleOrDefault(x => !x.IsCompleted && x.Guid == guid);
                var prod = this._rep.Get<Product>().Single(x => x.Id == productId);
            }
```

Comment: Are you creating your own server? Are you sending requests to an existing API?

Comment: yes I am using web api 2 as server and in the client I am using angularjs running on IIS express.

Comment: I will be glad to see your initial efforts first

Comment: Can send whatever way you want assuming back end can differentiate. Using REST methodology however you would use `put` for updates

Comment: REST is a convention, not a solid rule set that the framework respects. For example, the framework will allow you to delete an object from a GET request, or get an object from a DELETE request. But if you're following proper rest conventions, you shouldn't do tht.

Comment: thanks manson .. nice explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use POST, although it is not the proper REST implementation.

I'm not sure if you posted a code that does not work or just a question.

If it doesn't work, it might be because you send `guid` as a query parameter instead of sending it in the request's body.

Do one of the following:

```
$http.post(API_BASE_URL + '/Card/AddItem', {
    guid: cartGuid,
    productId: productId,
    quantity: quantity
}).success(function (data) {
    alert('added succesfully');
});
```

or:

```
public IHttpActionResult AddItem([FromUri]Guid guid, int productId, int quantity = 1)
```